# Do NodeJS events pass up to their parent functions?

Tags: node.js

If a child function in Node.JS emits an event, would the parent functions of that functions emit the same event? Like how they do in browser DOM? Or would `this` need to be passed down to the children to have the events emitted of off?

From the [Node Docs](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_event_uncaughtexception), it mentions "bubbling up the event loop," and I was just wondering if this works for custom emitted events as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not proper to do this, and I'm aware of this, but here's my temporary fix for handling events with multiple files.

I just emit the event and listen on the `process` object. Yes, it's sinful. There are several event listeners already there. If you are watching for more than 2 or 3 events of your own on `process`, you are asking for a memory leak, but it works.

I will investigate whether another global can be created and worked with. I have a feeling Node's upcoming support for `domain` will make this all easier.

Answer (score 0):

[Hap](https://github.com/johngeorgewright/hap) is a node module that can provide something like what you're asking. You set parents or children of each emitter and then let the bubbling take place.